# Changing proxy cache key nginx server

Tags: proxy, nginx

I would like to understand how to change the proxy_cache_key in Nginx:

> proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$uri;

I have found the documentation related to it but I don't understand how to perform the change https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/content-cache/content-caching/. Which file should I modify to make the change effective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply the changes you need to modify nginx conf file.
The file is called `nginx.conf`. It can be located in different locations depending on the OS and install build but the typical location is:
`/usr/local/nginx/conf, /etc/nginx or /usr/local/etc/nginx`.

This file is a main conf file for the whole server. But it can include the configuration from the child conf files located in the subfolders. This is normally used for different virtual servers running on one nginx.

If you have such configuration you will need to identify first if you would like to apply the setting to a virtual server or to the whole nginx configuration.
Depending on it you will need to add/modify this setting in the main conf file or in the conf files of the virtual servers.

As mentioned in the docs you can include various caching directives in the http {}, server {}, or location {} context to control which responses are cached.

- http {} content applies to the whole server
- server {} applies to the specific virtual server
- location {} applies to the specific location in the virtual server where it's configured.

The typical structure of nginx.conf file is represented [in the official docs](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/).